# Is there an elegant / simple way to handle the logical flow for a wizard UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForm that consists of a few dozen UI elements (all server controls).  I have turned the whole page into a wizard-like user experience by separating the UI elements into distinct steps using asp:Placeholder controls and setting their visibilities between postbacks.  Only one placeholder is visible at a time.

If the UI experience consisted solely of moving from Step 1 through Step 10, it's pretty trivial to create a generic Next / Prev button handler to move through the steps.  However, there are a handful of UI elements that determine which steps (wizard panes) get displayed. (two radio buttons, two checkboxes on different pages)

Is there an elegant or simple way to achieve this flow logic without creating a dedicated Click handler for every Next/Prev button on the page?  If there is a pattern for this, it eludes me.

Comment: do you know about the  ASP.NET 2.0 Wizard Control?

Comment: Oh yes.  Yes I do. :|  I didn't use it because I don't like the way it hides the controls in codebehind.  When you have dozens of controls it's really inconvenient to call container.FindControl() every time you want to access a control.  However, does the Wizard control actually solve this problem?

Comment: Hmmm... looks like the Wizard Control has the same issue really: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5.aspx

Comment: i re-read your post and thought about it for a minute.  If I was doing what you are, I might create a class that acted as a "view model" of the entire wizard. Do you know what i mean by that?  I am having trouble articulating this..

Comment: After more research and reading the answers here, I'm thinking the answer to my original question is "No."

Comment: I disagree that it's "no" - I think we should rally here and get the right design :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [jQuery Form Wizard](http://thecodemine.org/)

I recently converted a form into a wizard and it works very nice.  It might just work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Master Page 


Add your nav buttons to the master page.

Create an abstract base class that inherits from Web.UI.Page.

```
 public abstract class WizardPage: Page
    {
        public abstract void NextStep();
        public abstract void PreviousStep();
    }
```

Add abstract methods for NextStep and PreviousStep.

Create each wizard step as a separate page that inherits from the base class.

Implement NextStep and PreviousStep step on each page with the appropriate navigation.

Wire your buttons on the master page to call the active page's method...

```
 protected void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page is WizardPage)
            {
                WizardPage wizPage = (WizardPage)Page;
                wizPage.NextStep();
            }
        }
```

All that being said -- I'd check out the wizard control.

Comment: +1; This isn't very "elegant", because it isn't highly declarative (just specifying the page order, and letting some small bootstrap code or a framework handle the rest).  But the nice thing about this solution is you can make your handler logic as complicated as you want, so you can have wizards that aren't perfectly linear (e.g. inserting an extra page if a check box is checked).

Comment: I think this would be good in certain situations... but not for this particular one.  For my form all these controls represent data in a single DB row.  With this multi-page solution I'd have to be loading/saving this data over and over again for each step or modifying some Session object.  Kind of a deal-breaker here.  But thanks for the suggestion.  I do like the encapsulation of the steps... could definitely be handy.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Wizard control a number of times to handle the type of situation you describe. It takes a bit of study, like anything else, but can be made to provide a nice user experience. Controls that should be shown at each step of the wizard are declared inside a WizardStep template and it works out just great.